# Timeline header python modification

Tags: python, interface

I would like to add a custom frame rate slider in the timeline header, but I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

I've tried to add following line in `space_time.py` (between line 75 and 77), but nothing happens:

```
layout.prop(scene, "render.fps", text="")
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: depends on where you added that line..

Comment: In "space_time.py" between lines 75 and 77

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how it should be :

`layout.prop(scene.render, "fps", text="fps")` 
since the property is `fps`  and it is in `scene.render`

Answer (score 4):

*I'd suggest write an Add-on instead of edit the python files which shipped with blender, simply because you can update Blender as you like.*

Also it's fairly simple to append a property or a custom menu to the editor headers. Take a look into the python templates: *Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Menu*. Key  is to register `bpy.types.EDITOR_TYPE.append(draw)` and *append* a *custom method* to display the property.

---

#### Display a single property

To display a property in the timeline header use: `bpy.types.TIME_HT_header.append(draw)`:

[image]

```
import bpy

def draw_frame_rate_property(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    layout = self.layout

    # call the property
    layout.prop(scene.render, "fps", text="FPS")

def register():
    # lets add the menu to the timeline header via append or prepend
    bpy.types.TIME_HT_header.append(draw_frame_rate_property)

def unregister():  
    # remove header menu
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.remove(draw_frame_rate_property)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

#### Display multiple properties as menu

For a custom **frame rate menu in your timeline**, create a menu class (see the *UI Menu* template) and call [**layout.menu**](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.menu) for reference in your *draw function*. Following Add-on creates a new menu in the timeline header to edit all frame rate properties:

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Set Frame Rate in Timeline",
    "description": "",
    "author": "poor",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 73, 0),
    "location": "Timeline > Header",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Timeline"
}

import bpy

class CustomFrameRateMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Frame Rate"
    bl_idname = "RENDER_MT_framerate_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout

        #frame rate properties
        layout.prop(scene.render, "fps_base", text="FPS Base")
        layout.prop(scene.render, "fps", text="FPS")
        layout.menu("RENDER_MT_framerate_presets", text="Presets", icon="SCENE")

def draw_frame_rate_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu(CustomFrameRateMenu.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    # lets add the menu to the timeline header via append or prepend
    bpy.types.TIME_HT_header.append(draw_frame_rate_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

    # remove header menu
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.remove(draw_frame_rate_menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Note:** Use `bpy.types.EDITOR_TYPE.prepend()` to display the property before the menu:

[image]

---

**Further information:**

- [Add Custom Menu at Specific Location in the Header](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/add-custom-menu-at-specific-location-in-the-header)
- http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html?highlight=append#menu-item

Comment: Thanks, really useful! But the thing is, I also wanted to change the layout of the header elements: http://i.imgur.com/LF60YIS.png
And I guess that wouldn't be possible with an addon, right?

Comment: @Zafio Right, you can only append and prepend, adding inbetween existing elements seems to be really _hacky_ at the moment, see the answer (and the comments) of CoDEmanX: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/add-custom-menu-at-specific-location-in-the-header/3403#3403