# How to add custom color picker in blender material panel?

Tags: python, scripting, properties, color

I would like to add a custom colour picker for a custom *material* section. The colour picker should be below the red line in the image:

[image: Color picker position]

I found a code but this make the colour picker on the "tool panel" and not on the "material panel". This is the code:

```
import bpy


class POSE_PT_test(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Testing"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
            self.layout.prop(context.scene, "test_color", text='Detail Color')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(POSE_PT_test)
    bpy.types.Scene.test_color = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
        name="myColor",
        subtype="COLOR",
        size=4,
        min=0.0,
        max=1.0,
        default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    )

register()
```

Hope someone can help me to change this code so that it will be on material panel and below the red line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To change your test code to be a panel in materials tab of properties space use   `bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'` and  `bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'` and `bl_context = "material"` .  As for adding under red line in image above, (without an ugly hack) would need to edit into the draw code of that panel.

Comment: Related [Rearranging elements of a panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57214/rearranging-elements-of-a-panel)

Comment: @batFINGER Can you guide me to make it under the red line in the image above? I have tried the code suggested by you but it gives error on line `bpy.utils.register_class(POSE_PT_test)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "material"
```

The panel will end up like this

```
class POSE_PT_test(Panel):
    bl_label = "The title in the materials section"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "material"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    tag = 0
  
    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(context.scene, "test_color", text='Detail Color')
```

This is a little late but hope it can help anyone else that comes here