# Hide header from python

Tags: python, scripting

I need to hide the part of the header that has transform orientation, snapping etc. buttons using python script.

`bpy.context.space_data.show_region_tool_header = False` hides the entire header, but I need to keep showing Menu and Tool Settings.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Also had this issue a while ago but I think it's still not possible to manipulate headers the way it should be. However, if you really want to go down into the rabbit hole you can change `space_view3d.py` by an addon removing the lines temporary: [Rearranging elements of a panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57276/3710) or [re-define the draw](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57261/3710) method of the header.

Comment: @p2or OMG, this a very deep hole! I will be sued by the user if I do this with his / her installation through my script :) But thank you for giving an insight into Blender UI. BTW,  it looks like VIEW3D_PT_view3d_meshdisplay is no more there in 2.8.

Comment: @p2or I guess, I did not explore the pointer given by you thoroughly. Sorry about that. As suggested in the thread, setting the draw reference to a dummy function does the trick. The menu object in this case is: bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_tool_header. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Re-read your question right now, I'm sure you already know that but just for the sake: you can temporary hide the elements in order to display some text onto the header area like the grab operator does for example, there is: `C.area.header_text_set("string")` and you can also pass an empty string of course... Cheers!