# How to change the order of a custom function added in the dropdown menu in the header region in 2.81 with python

Tags: python, 3d-view, interface, edit-mode

**The duplicate post doesn't address the items in the dropdown. Only the bpy.types. The dropdown isn't part of that.**

I'm have added a custom function to the face dropdown in the header region when in Edit mode. by appending to `bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_faces`

How do I change the order of my function in the dropdown list?

[Here is a similar question but is addressing a different part of the UI.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/add-custom-menu-at-specific-location-in-the-header)

what it looks like now:
[image: what it looks like now]

what I want to see happen (doctored image):
[image: what I want to see happen (doctored image)]

The script so far:

```python
bl_info = {
    "name": "Custom Algo",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "Face",
}

import bpy

class CustomAlgo(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Custom Algo"""
    bl_idname = "face.Custom_algo"
    bl_label = "Custom Algo"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Pretend that you have done something sticky with that face")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(CustomAlgo.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomAlgo)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_faces.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomAlgo)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_faces.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: The answer is still the same as the question you linked: You can either `prepend` or `append` or do one of the workarounds listed.

Comment: I think the existing answers are not clear. The accepted answer has dead links in it... A clear and well structured answer would be useful. I am voting to reopen it.

Comment: @Školstvo, you can [re-register the whole menu in an add-on](https://pastebin.com/VnWadqYK). You can right-click Blender's UI in some places and choose edit source to find out stuff like this. This menu is copied from source.

Comment: Right clicking anything in Blender 2.8 doesn't really do much of interest.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about [this](https://i.imgur.com/y4a3aNJ.png)

Comment: Sweet, didn't know about that.

Comment: I thought that re-registering a complete menu would mess up other add-ons trying to add stuff to it, but it seems to work when I test it even if I have one addon with new menu and another appending to it and in fact it's on a header that I have completely rewritten in another addon... I am not a professional programmer and lack in-depth knowledge in the area so there might be other problems with this, but I can see none at the moment.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot     The workarounds don't really work for items in the dropdown list. When I hover over the existing items I see a reference to the operators that are activated by the elements, No reference to the elements themselves.

Comment: My tip is accept you can, easily,  either append or prepend to layout.  Whether  inserting layout  between operators in a menu's draw method or layout between menus (let's call it a menu not a drop down list) in a header's draw method (the dupe, now with a links fixed answer) the methods needed to achieve this, including code injection here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57214/rearranging-elements-of-a-panel  are IMO not worth the hassle.  Instead spend your time on  the _"script so far"_