# TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.append add menus in two places?

Tags: python

I try to add custom menus to the menus at the top bar in 2.80. The old INFO_HT_HEADER.append() doesn't work any more. I found TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.append() to kind of do the trick but I get two menus, one after the workspace tabs (would preferably have it before but I guess that is a feature request separate from this) and one after the view layer menu. Am I using the wrong thing or is this a bug? Here's a super simple menu from an example which gives me the problem.

```
import bpy

class customMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "view3D.custom_menu"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


def draw_item(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu(customMenu.bl_idname)

bpy.utils.register_class(customMenu)
bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.append(draw_item)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want additional menus in the top bar you can add them to `TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus`. The following code adds a menu called *Custom Menu* with a sub menu that contains an operator. The `draw()` function of `TOPBAR_MT_custom_menu` is for drawing the sub menu, while `menu_draw()` is appended to the `TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus` in order to draw the menu itself.

[image]

```
import bpy


class TOPBAR_MT_custom_sub_menu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Sub Menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


class TOPBAR_MT_custom_menu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Custom Menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.menu("TOPBAR_MT_custom_sub_menu")

    def menu_draw(self, context):
        self.layout.menu("TOPBAR_MT_custom_menu")


classes = (TOPBAR_MT_custom_sub_menu, TOPBAR_MT_custom_menu)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus.append(TOPBAR_MT_custom_menu.menu_draw)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus.remove(TOPBAR_MT_custom_menu.menu_draw)
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Switching TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar to TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus solven my problem, thanks.