# Select by certain vertex color

Tags: selection-tools, vertex-colors, select

Is there a way to select all faces with the same vertex color of the selected face? There is an old addon, but it doesn't work in the new version of Blender:
https://gist.github.com/tamask/2590850

Comment: To upgrade linked addon  replace `bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)` with `bpy.utils.register_class(SelectByColor)`  and change blender version in the header dict eg `'blender': (2, 80, 0),` for blender 2.8

Comment: @batFINGER I love how you just *know* these things :). It sounds like sorcery to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But still I can't get the addon to work... I think the code has to be updated in some way, because Blender doesn't let me to enable the addon and instead gives me this message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'select_by_color_2'

Answer (score -1):

I checked [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/add-custom-menu-at-specific-location-in-the-header) about properly registering the class and ended up modifying the end of the script like so:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectByColor)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SelectByColor)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

- script is broken though

ended up just using this one: https://blenderartists.org/t/select-vertices-according-to-vertex-color/471451/10

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/156177)