# How to add a button to outliner header via python script?

Tags: python, outliner

Is it possible to add a button via python to here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header of the outliner panel can be accessed through `bpy.types.OUTLINER_HT_header`. It is possible to add additional buttons to the header by appending or prepending a draw function which assigns the relevant operators to the layout. The draw function could look like the following, if your operator class is called `EXAMPLE_OT_something`.

```
def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator(EXAMPLE_OT_something.bl_idname)
```

If the operator has been registered the draw function can be appended to the header. This places the button *at the end* of the header. Using `.prepend` would place it *at the beginning*.

```
bpy.types.OUTLINER_HT_header.append(draw)
```

Below is an example add-on that demonstrates the concept.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Outliner Header Button",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 81, 0),
    "location": "Outliner",
    "description": "Adds an example button to the outliner header.",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Outliner"}

import bpy


class EXAMPLE_OT_something(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.something"
    bl_label = "Do something"
    bl_description = "This operator does something"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Hello")
        return {"FINISHED"}


def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(EXAMPLE_OT_something.bl_idname)


classes = (EXAMPLE_OT_something,)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_HT_header.append(draw)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_HT_header.remove(draw)
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Changing the order of entries requires more work though. It's not impossible but an add-on should probably avoid that (see [this old answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/add-custom-menu-at-specific-location-in-the-header))