# How to place a checkbox into 3dView Header

Tags: python, interface

I wrote a simple script to quickly (by hotkey) change Object Origin transformation options, but I want a good indication that this is enabled or disabled, and the most better way is to add a checkbox to a 3DView header, near with Options dropdown - see the fake shot. Spend a lot of time how to add it to it, but no luck! ((

[image]

```
#todo: Make it as a checkbox in Header

bl_info = {
    "name": "PivotToggle",
    "author": "MikeMS",
    "version": (1,0),
    "blender": (2,93,0),
    "category": "Object",
    "location": "Add to QuickFavorites from Search Operator or to a Hotkey for object.pivottoggle",
    "description": "Toggle Affect Only Origins and Parent for Object transformations.",
}

import bpy

class PivotToggle(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Toggle Affect Only Origins and Parent for Object transformations."""
    bl_idname = "object.pivottoggle"
    bl_label = "PivotToggle"


    def execute(self, context):
        
        #Script start: 
        
        if bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin == False and bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_skip_children == False:
            bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = True
            bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_skip_children = True
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Pivot Transformation Enabled")
        else:
            bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = False
            bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_skip_children = False
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Pivot Transformation Disabled")

        
        #Script end.
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PivotToggle)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PivotToggle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Thanks for a help!

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196045/how-to-add-a-button-to-outliner-header-via-python-script) is similar, but you need to adapt to the 3D Viewport instead of the outliner.  [This manual entry](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Header.html) is the starting point for searching for the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "PivotToggle",
    "author": "MikeMS",
    "version": (1,0),
    "blender": (2,93,0),
    "category": "Object",
    "location": "Add to QuickFavorites from Search Operator or to a Hotkey for object.pivottoggle",
    "description": "Toggle Affect Only Origins and Parent for Object transformations.",
}

import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_pivot_toggle(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Toggle Affect Only Origins and Parent for Object transformations."""
    bl_idname = "object.pivot_toggle"
    bl_label = "PivotToggle"
    
def execute(self, context): 
    if bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin == False and bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_skip_children == False:
       bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = True
       bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_skip_children = True
       self.report({'INFO'}, "Pivot Transformation Enabled")
    else:
       bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = False
       bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_skip_children = False
       self.report({'INFO'}, "Pivot Transformation Disabled")

    return {'FINISHED'}

def origin(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    mode_string = context.mode
    tool_settings = context.tool_settings
    if mode_string == 'OBJECT':
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(tool_settings, "use_transform_data_origin", text="Origins")
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_pivot_toggle)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.append(origin)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_pivot_toggle)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.remove(origin)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I think you want to remove `_tool` from your append and remove routines, as the OP wants the question in the view header.  I hope you don't mind that I did that.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!!! It works!)

Comment: Hmm, strange, by checking this checkbox enables only origins (not both origins and parents options), I need to understand it better how it works...))
P.S.: Oh, yep, I understand why it's that)...
Thanks)

Comment: @MikeMS don't leave us hanging.  What did you have to change to get it to work?

Comment: @marty-fouts It's all fine. But I returned return {'FINISHED'} because without it hotkey starts to throw an error about incorrect return value and stops working.

Comment: doh.  I missed that that had gone missing when I made my small change.  Fixed.