# How do you access the TEXT_EDITOR header so you can add an operator?

Tags: python, operator

I'm trying to create a button in the Header of the TEXT_EDITOR but for some reason the button isn't actually appearing in the header when I run the code? I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
import bpy

def main(self, context):
    text = bpy.data.texts.get(self.text)
    if text is not None:
        text = "exec(compile(" + repr(text) + ".as_string(), '" + text.name + "', 'exec'))"
        bpy.ops.console.clear_line()
        bpy.ops.console.insert(text=text)
        bpy.ops.console.execute()

class TEXT_EDITOR_OT_run_file(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'console.run_file'
    bl_label = 'Run File in Console'
    
    text = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.ui_type == 'CONSOLE'
    
    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class TEheader(bpy.types.Header):
    bl_idname = 'TEXT_EDITOR_HT_newheader'
    bl_label = 'New Header'
    bl_space_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        print ('code ran')
        self.layout.operator(TEXT_EDITOR_OT_run_file.bl_idname, icon='CONSOLE')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEheader)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEheader)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    print ('registered')
```

I found another article [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196045/how-to-add-a-button-to-outliner-header-via-python-script) that seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but when I attempted something similar with my code, it didn't work. It said that TEXT_EDITOR_HT_header is not a valid attribute of bpy.types so I assumed that blender has since been updated and you can no longer reference headers that way anymore.

I tried reformatting so that instead I was creating a new header and drawing the button, but nothing changes and the `print('code ran')` bit that I put in didn't run, and I can't figure out how to get it to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Result:

You can see the operator button added to the header
[image]

### Answer:

You were on the right path. The link you shared shows how to add extra items in headers. You don't need to create new header class for that. you can append draw function to the header.

> it said that TEXT_EDITOR_HT_header is not a valid attribute of bpy.types

Yes if you type `bpy.types.TEXT` in console, autocomplete shows that headerin  text editor can be accessed now via `bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer`

[image]

You can achieve what you are trying with this code. Important code blocks are these 2:

```py
def draw_item(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator('console.run_file', icon='CONSOLE')
```

```py
bpy.types.TEXT_HT_header.append(draw_item)
```

## Full Code:

```py
import bpy

def main(self, context):
    text = bpy.data.texts.get(self.text)
    if text is not None:
        text = "exec(compile(" + repr(text) + ".as_string(), '" + text.name + "', 'exec'))"
        bpy.ops.console.clear_line()
        bpy.ops.console.insert(text=text)
        bpy.ops.console.execute()

class TEXT_EDITOR_OT_run_file(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'console.run_file'
    bl_label = 'Run File in Console'
    
    text = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.ui_type == 'CONSOLE'
    
    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        
def draw_item(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator('console.run_file', icon='CONSOLE')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEXT_EDITOR_OT_run_file)
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_header.append(draw_item)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_header.remove(draw_item)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEXT_EDITOR_OT_run_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

#### Note:

In the Code you have posted, You are not registering the operator.

Comment: I thought `bpy.utils.register_class()` registered the operator? What do you mean that I'm not registering the operator

Comment: `bpy.utils.register_class(TEXT_EDITOR_OT_run_file)` This line is missing in the code snippet